# How Can I Combine Bitmap's RGBA in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem of Pixel.

I wanted to combine Bitmap's RGBA. And I got It.

But, haapend some problem.

First of all, show you my Code.

My Code:

```
    private Bitmap getImg (IntPtr hWnd, int width, int height, int startX, int startY) {
        IntPtr hDC = Win32.GetDC(hWnd);
        IntPtr hMemDC = Win32.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        IntPtr hBitmap = Win32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, width, height);

        if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero) {
            IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr) Win32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
            Win32.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDC, startX, startY, 13369376);
            Win32.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
            Win32.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
            Win32.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
            Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            Win32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            GC.Collect();
            return bmp;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void checkPixel (Bitmap img) {
        try {
            if (img != null) {
                long value = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++) {
                        Color pixel = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                        value += pixel.A + pixel.R + pixel.G + pixel.B;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("value : " + value);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    // And.. I used this way
    Bitmap img = getImg(hWnd, width, height, startX, startY);
    if (img != null) {
       checkPixel(img);
    }
```

So.. This code is working cool my computer.

But, work in another computer, "value" is different than my "value".

BMP is same. (Game Screen)

I don't understand this problem.

How can I solve this problem ?

Do you have a better idea ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong inside `checkPixel` so I would say that the bitmap you are checking is definitely different.

Comment: @Rotem : I worked get screenshot in same game, same point(x,y). But, result BMP is different. It is possible ?

Comment: Different screen settings (color depths)?

Comment: @TaW : uhm.. Maybe color or dpi ? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Taw : Hey bro! you are right. my computer is HighColor, another computer is TrueColor. Thanks :). So.. Finally, I can sleep ! Ilove you bro ~!